# Cant Find Class In Delphi

Tags: class, delphi

I have a delphi Application that has 3 units in it currently.

I have 2 forms `Start_Interface_u`,`Login_u`
and a additional unit (with no form) called `TMobileSystem_u`.

In `TMobileSystem_u` I have a few classes.

```
TWebSystem = Class
  Protected
    FRequest: TRequest;

  Public
    Constructor Create();
    Function Login(SUsername: String; SEmail: String; SPassword: String): String;
End;
```

But when I add the unit to the uses of any of my forms I cant reference a class.

For Example:
In `Login_u` I would like to add a variable called `WebSystemInterface : TWebSystem` problem is that it doesn't find either the `TMobileSystem_u` in the uses when I use `crtl + space` and it doesn't find the class when I declare it as a variable.

What could be wrong ? Does anyone know ?

** Edit

This is the output after attempting to compile the project

```
Checking project dependencies...
Compiling Exotic_Pets.dproj (Debug, Win32)
dcc command line for "Exotic_Pets.dpr"
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\bin\dcc32.exe -$O- -$W+ --no-config -M -Q -TX.exe -AGenerics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;
  Generics.Defaults=System.Generics.Defaults;WinTypes=Winapi.Windows;WinProcs=Winapi.Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE -DDEBUG 
  -E.\Win32\Debug -I"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\lib\Win32\debug";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\lib\Win32\release";
  C:\Users\Jacques\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Imports;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\Imports";
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Dcp;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\include";"C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Raize\CS5\Lib\RS-XE6\Win32" -LEC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Bpl -LNC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Dcp 
  -NU.\Win32\Debug -NSWinapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap; -O"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\lib\Win32\release";C:\Users\Jacques\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Imports;"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\Imports";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Dcp;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\include";
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Raize\CS5\Lib\RS-XE6\Win32" -R"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\lib\Win32\release";
  C:\Users\Jacques\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Imports;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\Imports";
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Dcp;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\include";"C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Raize\CS5\Lib\RS-XE6\Win32" -U"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\lib\Win32\debug";"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\lib\Win32\release";C:\Users\Jacques\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Imports;"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\Imports";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Dcp;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\14.0\include";
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Raize\CS5\Lib\RS-XE6\Win32" -V -VN -NBC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\Dcp 
  -NHC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\hpp -NO.\Win32\Debug   Exotic_Pets.dpr   
[dcc32 Error] Login_u.pas(39): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TWebSystem'
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Start_Interface_u.pas(43): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'Login_u.pas'
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:00.3
```

Comment: Are you possibly adding the `TMobileSystem_u` unit in the implementation uses clause and attempting to add a reference to `TWebSystem` in the Interface section?

Comment: @Andy_D - I'm adding the unit in the uses at the top because I would like to add the variable in the `protected` declarations of the form

Comment: Silly question, but have you actually tried to compile the project or are you relying on Class Completion?

Comment: I've actually tried to compile the project then I get the error (See edited version of my question)

Comment: Are all the source files in the same folder? Without seeing the code for `Login_u` it's difficult to know what's going on. Does the `TMobileSystem_u` unit compile in another project?

Comment: nope, `TMobileSystem_u` is unique to this project, `Login_u` depends completely on the functions in `TMobileSystem_u` which it can't access so for now `Login_u` is empty with no actual code in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54117/discussion-between-user3564246-and-andy-d).

Answer (score 4):

1. That happens if your units are in different folders and their paths are not set in DPR nor project "Search Paths".
2. Ctrl+Space may not always suggest the full length of available units when used in `uses` section. I'd skip this clue.
3. If you add unit into `implementation` section, you can not access it's constatnts/classes/etc prior to that (e.g. in TForm fields, types definitions and var sections)
4. Classes declared in the `implementation` section can not be seen or accessed by other units.